# Removing a % character from a string in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a string in my database like this

SKU-SKU%5B1%5Drt76228

and I want to get rid of the % signs, but because they are a wildcard character I am unsure how to do this. I am using mySQL.

Comment: Could you give an example of the result you seek? What query have you tried so far?

Comment: You sure you'd like just remove the percent char, but not decode these %5B, %5D & Co to their original form?

Comment: Hi, I've been using the SELECT REPLACE function to find it and remove it. But when I search for that string exactly it uses the % as a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE('SKU-SKU%5B1%5Drt76228', '%', '');
```

Comment: when I try that, it uses the % as a wildcard and doesn't find that string.

Comment: Try using the below code. This should work with SQL Server. You have to put it in a loop and replace all the % values. `SELECT CHARINDEX('%', 'SKU-SKU%5B1%5Drt76228') AS MatchPositionToBeReplaced;`